# Как проверить функцией в запросе наличие записи в таблице?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Какой должен быть запрос c функцией `chek_user_id`, чтобы проверить, есть ли такой `iD` таблице пользователей?

Если есть - вернуть `true`, а если нет - вернуть `false`.

Comment: [EXISTS Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions013.htm#SQLRF52167).

Comment: _Какой должен быть запрос_ - а какой вам нужен?

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя вернуть булево значение - `true` или `false` в запросе, так как в SQL этого [типа данных](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-A3C0D836-BADB-44E5-A5D4-265BA5968483) нет.

---

Воспользуетесь другими доступными типами данных и константными значениями, которые могут послужить заменителями условных значений: `1/0`, `'true'/'false'`, `'yes'/'no'` и тп.
Главный критерий выбора - читаемость кода. Такой запрос поймут скорее всего все:

```
select id, name, checkIfUserExists (1) "userExists" 
from users
where checkIfUserExists (1) = 'y';

        ID NAME   userExists
---------- ------ ----------
         1 user 1 y
```

Попробуйте:

```sql
create table users as 
    select 1 id, 'user 1' name from dual
/    
create or replace function checkIfUserExists (id number) return char is
begin
    for r in (select 1 from users where id=checkIfUserExists.id) loop
        return 'y';
    end loop;
    return 'n';
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function check_user_id(in_id integer) return boolean is
  v_count integer;
begin
  select
    count(t.id) into v_count
  from table_of_user t
  where t.id = in_id;

  return(v_count <> 0);
end;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.